# Copy only the most-recently-modified files from Finder search results, preserving directory structure/hierarchies on macOS?

Tags: macos, backup, file-transfer, finder, automator

I found results for similar variations of this question, but none that really provided a solution for my specific case.

I have a lot of preset files with a specific extension (.tfx) on a backup drive. The files are scattered around in different folder paths within a specific backup folder structure. I need to find a way to copy all of these files with their directory structure intact, and I need to be able to filter the searched results by date range, and only keep the most recently modified versions of any file.

e.g.

```
Source:
BackupDrive/Backup_20201201/folder1/subfolder1/subfolderA/file1.tfx
BackupDrive/Backup_20191101/folder1/subfolder1/subfolderA/file1.tfx
BackupDrive/Backup_20201001/folder2/subfolder2/subfolderA/file2.tfx
BackupDrive/Backup_20200901/folder3/subfolder3/subfolderC/file3.tfx

Destination:
Documents/FromBackup/folder1/subfolder1/subfolderA/file1.tfx
Documents/FromBackup/folder1/subfolder2/subfolderA/file2.tfx
Documents/FromBackup/folder2/subfolder3/subfolderC/file3.tfx
```

The catch here is the ability to find and copy ***only*** the specific file type, and only ***modified within a specific date range***, and so that older versions of the same file in the same relative path would be overwritten by the newest versions without prompting me to confirm every case where this occurs (because there will be hundreds of them).

I also need to eliminate the dated backup folders from the target hierarchy so that there is only one hierarchy in the target path instead of several copies from backups I made on different dates.

The ideal solution would be to make an app using Automator so that I could simply use Finder to find the files I want to copy within a specific backup path and modified date range, then drag/drop all of those results onto the app, which would then prompt me for the parent/destination folder for the files I want to copy with their folder hierarchies intact. And if any of the files being copied exist in the target location and have a more recent modification date, the newer files would not be overwritten.

I figured out how to do this on Windows 10 using a batch script and robocopy to basically sync changes from one folder path to another on a mounted network drive. But I'm not sure how I can do this on macOS.

Thank you in advance for anyone who can help with this!

Comment: Most people use rsync for stuff like this on Macs and Linux boxes. It’s very powerful, and a bit complicated, but I’m very confident it can meet just about all the requirements you have.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410629/copy-files-from-finder-search-results-with-directory-structure-hierarchies-intac

Comment: @jimtut Can you please elaborate on what rsync is and how to use it to fulfill my needs, and maybe post it as an answer so I can vote it up if I find that it works for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Recommend that you use `rsync`: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync (or various other Google-able references)

Rsync is very powerful, but it can be complex.  Start with a very simple command (recommend placing into a simple shell script to make it easier to edit and run) that just syncs 2 small directories.

Then start looking at the more complicated options to meet your requirements, like `--include` or `--include-from-file`.  I'm very confident that you will be able to meet all or most of your requirements with just rsync, but you will need to figure out the options that you need by yourself, based on the many, many rsync references out there and your experimentation.

If you get most of the way there and are stuck on one particular requirement that you can't make work w/ rsync, post a new question with your script so far and where you are stuck.  The SE sites aren't here to write scripts for you.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help. I've seen other answers to questions here that included specific scripts to solve the problem. I was just hoping I might be lucky enough to get that kind of help. But unfortunately, it looks like I'll need to just give up on this since I'm far too weighted down by other far more daunting and oppressive problems I need to deal with, and don't have the time, energy, or willpower to "figure it out" on my own this time. I'm barely hanging on by a thread as is. :(